# Search text field and replace with value from column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data frame and I need to search the last column for the column names of the other columns  and replace the found text with the value from the appropriate column.  Using the sample data below the first row would work like this:

- the text "date" should be replaced with "2019-05-12" in the `Query` column
- text "substitute" should be replaced with "1" in the `Query` column
- text "lower" should be replaced with "150" in the `Query` column
- text "upper" should be replaced with "250" in the `Query` column

I tried the `str_replace` function from `stringr` but it did not work maybe I am using the function incorrectly. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
data=structure(list(date = c("2019-05-12", "2019-07-10", "2019-04-10"
), substitute = c(1, 2, 3), lower = c(150, 100, 300), upper = c(250, 
                                                                200, 400), query = c("Select \r\ncolumn1,\r\ncolumn2,\r\ncase \r\nwhen \"date\" between a and b then 1\r\nwhen \"date\" between c and d then 2\r\nend as date_group,\r\ncase when \"date\" < e then \r\n'substitute' as ID\r\nFROM Table1\r\nWHERE (date_2 between a and d )\r\n      AND (tag between 'lower' and 'upper')\r\nGROUP BY", 
                                                                                     "Select \r\ncolumn1,\r\ncolumn2,\r\ncase \r\nwhen \"date\" between a and b then 1\r\nwhen \"date\" between c and d then 2\r\nend as date_group,\r\ncase when \"date\" < e then \r\n'substitute' as ID\r\nFROM Table1\r\nWHERE (date_2 between a and d )\r\n      AND (tag between 'lower' and 'upper')\r\nGROUP BY", 
                                                                                     "Select \r\ncolumn1,\r\ncolumn2,\r\ncase \r\nwhen \"date\" between a and b then 1\r\nwhen \"date\" between c and d then 2\r\nend as date_group,\r\ncase when \"date\" < e then \r\n'substitute' as ID\r\nFROM Table1\r\nWHERE (date_2 between a and d )\r\n      AND (tag between 'lower' and 'upper')\r\nGROUP BY"
                                                                )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap `{}` around the column names in `query` and evaluate it row-wise using `glue`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(glue)

output_data <- data %>%
   mutate(query_new = str_replace_all(query, paste0('\\b',names(.), '\\b',
                       collapse = "|"), function(m) paste0('{', m, '}'))) %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(query_new = as.character(glue(query_new)))


cat(output_data$query_new[1])

#Select 
#column1,
#column2,
#case 
#when "2019-05-12" between a and b then 1
#when "2019-05-12" between c and d then 2
#end as date_group,
#case when "2019-05-12" < e then 
 #'1' as ID
#FROM Table1
#WHERE (date_2 between a and d )
#      AND (tag between '150' and '250')
#GROUP BY
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` for each column :

```
rep_fun = function(df_row){
  df_row[5] = gsub("\"date\"",df_row[1],df_row[5])
  df_row[5] = gsub("substitute",df_row[2],df_row[5])
  df_row[5] = gsub("lower",df_row[3],df_row[5])
  df_row[5] = gsub("upper",df_row[4],df_row[5])
}
data[,"query"] = apply(data,1,rep_fun)
data
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer works like a charm I chose Ronak's answer because he gave me a generalizable answer I didn't know I needed.